# prediction applied to whole data

Tags: r, dataframe, lm

HI i am doing prediction with my data.if i use data.frame it throws the folloing error.

```
input(bedrooms="2",bathrooms="2",area="1000") were specified with different   types from the fit

here is my program

input <- function(bedrooms,bathrooms,area)
{
delhi <- read.delim("delhi.tsv", na.strings = "") 
delhi$lnprice <- log(delhi$price)
heddel <- lm(lnprice ~ bedrooms+ area+ bathrooms,data=delhi)
valuepred = predict (heddel,data.frame(bedrooms=bedrooms,area=area,bathrooms=bathrooms),na.rm = TRUE)
final_prediction = exp(valuepred)
final_prediction
}
```

if i remove the data.frame it predicts the value for over all data.i got the following output.

```
       1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
  15480952   11657414   10956873    6011639    6531880    9801468   16157549 
         9         10         11         14         15         16         17 
  10698786    5596803   14688143   20339651   22012831   16157618   26644246
```

but it needs to display one value only.

any idea how to resolve this..any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your code is missing a `,`.

Comment: This question is not showing any effort at all. A bracket is missing on the first line of code and text is mixed with the code. The code is not reproducible either...

Comment: hey sry now i updated the code.can u check now

Comment: We also don't have the data set you are building your models from (`delhi.tsv`). When asking on SO you should always supply a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because otherwise it is unnecessarily hard if not impossible to help you.

Comment: What exactly is the error? What are you trying to do? Your question is still not reproducible.

Comment: i am getting output like this.   1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
  15480952   11657414   10956873    6011639    6531880    9801468   16157549 
         9         10         11         14         15         16         17 
  10698786    5596803   14688143   20339651   22012831   16157618   26644246

Comment: but i need to get only one value.but it predicts for the whole data

Comment: The data you're using to predict need to be of the same format (column names and type) as the date you used to fit the model.

Answer (score 1):

Sharon, you want to make a prediction for the specific values of bedroom, bathroom and area, but are putting them in as character rather than numeric values. This is causing the error you are seeing. when you remove the data.frame statement from predict, it will produce predictions based on the data set used to build the model, i.e. delhi.

Try

```
input(bedrooms=2,bathrooms=2,area=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

The other answer should solve your problem, but if you really believe that `log(price)` is linear in `bedrooms + bathrooms + area` then you are better off with a generalized linear model (glm) in the poisson family. So something like:

```
fit <- glm(price~bedrooms+bathrooms+area, dehli, family=poisson)
```

Then predict using `type="response"`

```
pred <- predict(fit, data.frame(bedrooms, bathrooms, area), type="response")
```